# Discord.py slash commands not visible in server

Tags: discord.py

I've recently returned from a long break in bot development and realized that discord.py got re-continued by the developers.

I read that they added slash commands.

Refrence: https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/c4324f17a80c94776832430007ad40e6

In attempts to experiment with this I tried creating my own slash commands but the commands didn't seem to appear whenever I used discords built-in / function.

I did make sure my bot has admin in the server and also checked "application.commands" on the scope before authorizing the bot to join the server.

I also tried using the very code in the demonstration provided which lead to the same outcome of it not being visible.

[image: code used]

Comment: have you read the whole gist? it’s clearly shown that you have to manually sync the commands: https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/c4324f17a80c94776832430007ad40e6#syncing

Comment: I did use syncing at one point but it still won't show the slash commands when I try use them.

Comment: have you passed also the guild id into the sync method?